# At what point in the ASP.NET page/app life-cycle should I redirect a user based on his country?

Tags: asp.net, redirect

We have a web app where we need to redirect customers from `.com` to `.co.uk` domains based on the geolocation of ther IP address. When/where should I do this?

The content will change slightly based on their location, but I think I can handle that OK. However, if anyone has any comments on the best way to handle this, I'd like to hear those comments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an HttpModule.  It's the earliest place to do the redirection.

Comment: Doesn't Global.asax provide the same events an HttpModule has access to?

Comment: Yes, but there are couple reasons to prefer HttpModule.  Here is a good read: http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/06/12/146356.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in application code, I would do this as early as the IP is available, in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  //Redirect here...
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why I'd prefer code over a config setting?

Comment: There's no a config setting for this built in...that I've ever seen anyway, your options are an HttpModule, Global.asax code (ease of use/flexibility, though it's equivalent to an HttpModule in those aspects) or something in the form of an IIS module.

Comment: Global.asax is deprecated.  There are several good reasons to use HttpModule instead, and it's just as easy.

Comment: @Bryan - Can you please link me to where Global is deprecated?

Comment: Guess I can't... I was under the impression it was solely for backward compatibility, but the ASP.NET 3.5 documentation lists it without mentioning this.